"Friends" episode where Chandler says he hates his job and the rest of the gang say they love their jobs
I cannot find which episode of Friends has this scene: they all sit in Central Perk and Chandler says he hates his work, while the rest of the gang say they love their jobs.
I think the dialogue was more or less like this:

[Chandler]: I hate my job.
[Someone else]: You hate your job?
[Chandler]: Everybody hates their job.
[Everybody else]: I like my job. I love my work, etc.


The beginning of The One with Christmas in Tulsa (Season 9, Episode 10).

Monica: I can't believe you're not gonna be here for Christmas.
Ross: You're really not coming back?
Chandler: Yeah, we have all this paperwork that needs to be filed by
  the end of the year. If I don't get it done, I'll be fired.
Monica: It's so unfair, you don't even like your job!
Chandler: So, who does?
Phoebe: Oh, I like my job.
Joey: I love my job.
Rachel: Yeah, I can't wait to go back to work.
Ross: I can't get enough dinosaurs!

This (and the rest of the episode, where Chandler is stranded in Tulsa during Christmas with a woman who flirts with him) eventually makes Chandler realize he hates his job and he finally quits it and starts working in advertizing.

Thanks. Turns out the scene is not in Central Perk and I was sure about that.

And it was basically a clip show, wasn't it? I remember they did a lot of those in the last couple of years.

You mean if it was a recap? I found it online and it was a normal scene in the apartment of Monica and Chandler. They had this discussion while Chandler was leaving.

No, I mean the rest of the episode featured a lot of old clips.

Yes, you're right. It was made from Christmas episodes clips. I've watched each episode several times and I'm still surprised how many things I don't remember.
